# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: chromedriver 88.0.4324.150 for WIN64 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

It seems like my chromedriver is not updated by the below code:

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import testone2.firstTest;

import java.io.*;

public class testLogin {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    private int seconds;

    public testLogin() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        //Download the web driver executable
        String chromeVersion = null;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("chromeVersion.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                chromeVersion = line.trim();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Throwable ioException = new Throwable();
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version(chromeVersion).setup();
        boolean oldVersion = false;
        try {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            oldVersion = false;
            String err = e.getMessage();
            chromeVersion = err.split("version is")[1].split("with binary path")[0].trim();
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("chromeVersion.txt", true);
                writer.write(chromeVersion);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException er) {
            }
        }


        if (!oldVersion) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version(chromeVersion).setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

    }


    public void sleep(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Chrome is Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and WebDriverManager dependency is 4.2.2

This is returned in console:
`io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: chromedriver 88.0.4324.150 for WIN64 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`

Can anyone point out if its the code to read version of chromedriver at fault? What is the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: What's in the chromeVersion.txt ? There are no chromedriver_win64 versions, only the chromedriver_win32 exists.

Comment: It is 88.0.4324.150

Comment: How can i get it to download _win32 instead

Comment: @art_architect sorry had to ping

Comment: I'm not getting the error... On my side it just launches 2 chromes with your code... Are you trying to use to save an old chromedriver version?

Comment: Sorry not getting what you mean by "Save an old chromedriver version" @art_architect

Comment: That reading/writing the version in the text got me confused :). According to the documentation from here: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager you only have to have this line: WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); and it will detect the version. You dont need to specify an exact version. I'm glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting chromeversion.txt to 88.0.4324.96